# Why wouldn't Ajax call return success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

That ajax call technically functions. I mean, correct response headers are received, in precise accordance with the php script. However, it returns error.
Could anyone please take a look at it and maybe share a clue?

That is the chunk of my ajax call code.

```
success: function(data){
            var object_from_database = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (object_from_database.email_from_php=='wrong'){
                    $('#signin_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
                    $('#signin_feedback').html('E-mail не существует');
            }
            if (object_from_database.password_from_php=='wrong'){
                $('#signin_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
                    $('#signin_feedback').html('Неверный пароль');
            }
            if (object_from_database.password_from_php=='exists'){
                    $('#signin_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17"});
                    $('#signin_feedback').html('Введите пришедший на ваш E-mail код.');
                    $('#frcode_textarea').css({"visibility": "visible"});
                    $('#frcode_submit_button').css({"visibility": "visible"});
                    $('#frcode_sendagain_button').css({"visibility": "visible"});
            }
            if (object_from_database.authorize_login=='yes'){
                window.location.replace("http://letsrate.kz/favorit/profile.php?id="+object_from_database.session_id+"");
            }
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#signin_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
        $('#signin_feedback').html('Серверная ошибка');
    }
```

These are the errors that are displayed in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery.js:4
o.parseJSON jquery.js:4
$.ajax.success index.php:98
j jquery.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.js:2
x jquery.js:4
(anonymous function) jquery.js:4
```

Most of the errors come from jquery.js.
The only error to come from my script happens to originate at the same line with $.parseJSON. can the problem be directly or indirectly related to $.parseJSON?

Comment: how would you recommend to tackle the issue?

Comment: Start by opening your javascript debugger and looking at the network tab. What is returned?

Comment: problem solved. data received by the call was json already.

Comment: @OlegArsyonov: You mean the JSON had already be parsed into Javascript objects? If you tell jQuery to expect JSON, it will do that automatically.

Comment: yeah, I specified datatype to be json, but then I overlooked that while debugging